# Asp.net core. Получение данных из формы

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Всем привет, я новичок в asp.net core. Крч если коротко о проекте, то просто нужно на сайте вводить данные в форму( имя, телефон, описание проблемы) и заявка отправляется менеджеру в тг. Как получать данные в контроллер и отправлять в тг я понял. Но! Форма присутствует на всех страницах(находится в футоре в _Layout), а делать форму отдельной страницы не варик. Проблема в том что ведь когда отправляешь данные из формы, нужно указывать контроллер и метод, а как понять как понять какая у тебя щас открыта страница да и плюсом чтобы была валидация нужно возвращать представление, ну крч я не знаю как сделать. Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Используйте самые стандартные способы передачи данных, описанные в документации, любых туториалах, книгах. Например, в шаблонном коде свежесозданного проекта ASP.NET MVC в `_Layout.cshtml` присутствует обращение к `@ViewData["Title"]`. А задаётся это значение в представлениях контроллеров: `@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page"; }`. Таким же образом передавайте любые свои данные.